# Java - Bypassing polymorphism?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Lets say I have a class like this:

```
public class Base
{

    public void foo()
    {
        System.out.println("base foo");
    }

    public Base()
    {
        foo();
    }
}
```

and I have a derived class like this:

```
public class Derived extends Base
{
    public void foo()
    {
        System.out.println("derived foo");
    }
}
```

Because of polymorphism, when I create an instance of the derived class, when the base constructor gets implicitly called, the base constructor will call the derived method foo instead of the base foo. Is there any way to "force" the base constructor to call its own foo?

Comment: You can make `foo` final in the base class so that it can't be overriden.

Answer (score 9):

> Is there any way to "force" the base constructor to call its own foo?

No (assuming you want to be *able* to override `foo` in `Derived`) The *only* situation in which a call to a virtual method won't be executed polymorphically is when you call `super.whatever()` from a subclass - which will call the superclass implementation even if the subclass overrides it. That's not useful in your case as you want to call the implementation in the *same* class.

However you can use a variant of the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) (it not the same, but it's reminiscent of it...) to get the *effect* you want.

```
public class Base
{
    public void foo()
    {
        fooImpl();
    }

    private void fooImpl()
    {
        System.out.println("base foo");
    }

    public Base()
    {
        fooImpl();
    }
}
```

Now `foo()` itself is polymorphic as normal - but if (within Base) you ever want to execute "what `foo()` would do if it weren't overridden" you can just call `fooImpl()`.